# How to highlight live expressions when change on STMCubeIDE Debugging

Tags: debugging, stm32cubeide

I'm new to STMCubeIDE (I'm using the latest version, 1.10) and I've noticed that there's no highlight when an expression/variable on live expressions change its value.

I'm used to IAR which highlights in red when a expression/variable changes its value while debugging.

Is there a similar option for STMCubeIDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such option

ST team has take the suggestion into consideration

https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001eaQ8TSAU/how-to-highlight-live-expressions-when-change-on-stmcubeide-debugging